# Can assets be given to another player's character?

Tags: cortex-plus, leverage

If a player creates an asset in Leverage like **Baseball Bat d6** (paying the plot point to do so) can the PC then give the bat to some other PC? Of course they can in the fiction, but does the other PC gain the d6 as well?

If so, players could effectively give away their plot points, and that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I know it works that way in Marvel Heroic, but I'll let someone with specific knowledge answer here.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at the rules, but I'm pretty sure you can lend assets, though it's GM's discretion as to whether or not the character would (for instance, giving away a wallet photo of a loved one would be somewhat of a stretch, while giving a weapon, even a favorite one, could be done easily).

Answer (score 6):

As written, the Assert rules (p66) don't explicitly say, so it's up to you.  But, there are clues suggesting that it's reasonable.  Complications are basically the Fixer's Assets, and the game blesses the players using them. ("Complications and Player Cleverness", p 112-113)  The game also lets players create assets that change NPCs.  "The Role of Assets" (p114-115) in the paragraph about inspired assets.  A player might create asset like "Hard Up For Cash" or "Devout Catholic" to change an NPC.  And the biggest clue, "An Asset might change the problem—a thug with a gun is best dealt with by your Hitter dice, but if the thug with the gun is Having Second Thoughts d6, that may mean the Grifter can talk him down instead."  That strongly suggests that your Hitter might tag the thug with "Having Second Thoughts d6," which the Grifter can immediately make use of.

My suggestion is to allow it.  An individual d6 isn't that big of a deal, and it can work in universe.  I can see the "Having Second Thoughts" thing happening on the show: Eliot calls outs, "I can see you're shaking, are you having second thoughts?" then Sophie stepping in to close the deal.  I can see Eliot being in a tough fight surrounded by thugs, and Hardison, from hiding, sliding out a baseball bat for Eliot.  Or from the episode "The Gone-Fishin' Job" (S03E07), Hardison pays for "Distracted militia men d6" which Eliot immediately makes use of make their escape from the camp.

Comment: To add some additional quotes to the excellent answer above: pg 10 of the [Leverage RPG](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1931567247) states that "[assets] can be environmental, too" and gives the example or **SHADOWY**, and pg 13 gives "(**UNLOCKED DOOR D6**)" as an example of an asset as "part of the scenery" it also lists "(**HANDYMAN D6**)" to "effectively create a new Extra". All of these would apply to anyone in the area especially in light of the advice to the Fixer regarding the "picking up" of players' assets on pg 117.